# Как развернуть график zedgraph на всю форму

Tags: c#, winforms

Как развернуть график zedgraph на всю форму так как показано в скриншоте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И чтоб кнопка показать автоматически смещалась в нижний правый угол?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В меню свойства, есть Anchor - определяющий грани контейнера, к которому привязан элемент! С этим свойством поиграйся)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonHide.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
    zedgraph1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top))); 
}

private void buttonHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: buttonHide.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right))); Прописываю так в обработчике собития нажатия этой же кнопки, но не работает так. Почему?

Comment: Потому что надо чтобы свойства граней контейнера применились до нажатия кнопки!!

Comment: Я сделал так но как мне сделать так, теперь мне надо чтобы кнопку переместить  вниз, то есть изменить координату при нажатии на нее. Вот я пишу так "buttonHide.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(877, 718);" в обработчике события он смещает ее, но когда открываю форму на весь экран она остается там же. Как это исправить.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonHide.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        zedGraph.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top)));
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

    }

    int vkl = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        vkl++;
        if (vkl % 2 == 0)
        {
            buttonHide.Text = "Cкрыть";
            buttonHide.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(877, 510);
            //buttonHide.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            tabControl1.Visible = true;
            labelTimeStart.Visible = true;
            textBoxTimeStart.Visible = true;
            labelTimeFinish.Visible = true;
            textBoxTimeFinish.Visible = true;
            //labelBackGround.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 510);
            //zedGraph.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(940, 466);
        }
        else
        {
            buttonHide.Text = "Показать";

            //labelOfAxis1[0].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.labelBackGround.Location.X + 3, this.labelBackGround.Location.Y + 2);
            for (int j = 1; j < countOfAxis; j++)
            {
                //labelOfAxis1[j].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
                //labelOfAxis1[j].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(877, 718);
            }
            buttonHide.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(877, 718);
            //buttonHide.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            //zedGraph.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(940, 680);
            //zedGraph.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
            //| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
            //| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            tabControl1.Visible = false;
            labelTimeStart.Visible = false;
            textBoxTimeStart.Visible = false;
            labelTimeFinish.Visible = false;
            textBoxTimeFinish.Visible = false;
            //labelBackGround.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 718);

        }
    }
```

Comment: @IGOR ????????????????